# How to use Ionic and Angular In single folder structure

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi I'am Going to develop an application for both web and Mobile App using Angular and Ionic. Both having some similar  function like services etc. So I don't want to do it twice i need to maintain common folder structure for commonly using files

example :

```
src
│
├── Ionic
│   └── Project.ts
│
├── Angular
│   └── project.ts
│
└── service
    └── web service.ts (commonly accessing folder)
```

Comment: You can have 2 projets using the same sources. Did you try something ?

Comment: No i haven't tried.

Comment: Git submodules & Ionic 4?